# How to bind Repeater with list of objects GroupBy

Tags: c#, asp.net

First of all, Sorry for long detail. but its necessary to describe my problem. Every thing is self explainatory not so hard to read. Thanks!

I have list of Object from my class.  `List<CalendarEvent> allCalendarEvents = GetEvents();`

```
public class CalendarEvent
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public ID itemId { get; set; }
    public DateTime start { get; set; }
    public DateTime end { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
}
```

Now I wanted to group the events in the List `allCalendarEvents` by `start` date. So I used this code:

```
var monthList = from e in allCalendarEvents
                group e by e.start.Month into g
                orderby g.Key
                select new { month = g.Key, Event = g };
```

All the items in the list are now group by Month. So far so good. I used ASP Repeater to show the data to the user.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repMonths" OnItemDataBound="repMonths_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <%# Eval("month") %>
```

**Code Behind**

```
repMonths.DataSource = monthList;
repMonths.DataBind();
```

I can see the month number as output for my data, e.g. for the events in May, June,July, I see:

```
5
6
7
```

Now I want to show to the user how many CalenderEvents are inside one group of month. If I use use another repeater inside `repMonths` like this:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repMonths" OnItemDataBound="repMonths_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <%# Eval("month") %>
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repInnerEvent">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEventName"></asp:Label>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>    
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then I don't know how to bind data with inner repeater. E.g.

```
protected void repMonths_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var item = e.Item.DataItem as ???; // I don't know what will come here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you'll need to do is actually find the inner repeater. You are on the right track. Use `FindControl()` on the repeater item to find it. Then once you have it, just simply assign the data source and bind it.

```
protected void repMonths_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    // We only care if the repeater item is part of the <ItemTemplate>
    if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        Repeater repInnerEvent = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("repInnerEvent");
        repInnerEvent.DataSource = // your data source
        repInnerEvent.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Sounds like the question isn't actually how to bind. It is how to get the data to bind. In that case, you already have your query written. You just need to know the month. In that case, I would use a label to hold the month.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repMonths" OnItemDataBound="repMonths_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
           <asp:Label ID="lblMonth" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("month") %>'></asp:Label>
           <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repInnerEvent">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEventName"></asp:Label>
                    </li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>    
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then in the `ItemDataBound`, get that label and use its value.

```
protected void repMonths_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    // We only care if the repeater item is part of the <ItemTemplate>
    if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        // Get the month
        Label lblMonth = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblMonth");

        // Get the events for the month
        var eventList = from e in allCalendarEvents
                        where e.start.Month == lblMonth.Text
                        select e;

        // Bind your events to the inner repeater
        Repeater repInnerEvent = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("repInnerEvent");
        repInnerEvent.DataSource = eventList
        repInnerEvent.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: But still the same question ...How can I provide the `DataSource`? The DataSource in my case is the events which are grouped by Month.  How Can I provide this one group element ? Thanks..

Comment: Oh, so the question is how to get the data to bind? Not how to bind. Well it looks like you already have your query written. Just add a where clause where the month is the month of the current row.

Comment: See my edit. That should at least point you in the right direction.