# How to split data in a Custom List in a custom format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list `List<CalendarEvent> _eventsList` from the Class `CalendarEvent`

```
public class CalendarEvent
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime start { get; set; }
    public DateTime end { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
}
```

This is example of one of event I have in the list `_eventsList`:

```
id     start            end             subject
---    ----------    ------------      ------------------
21     05.10.2015     01.01.2016        its a  long Event
```

Now if the the difference between `start date` and `end date` is longer then 1 month as in above case then I want to split this in months as follows in C# code:

```
     start            end             subject
    ----------    ------------      ----------
    05.10.2015     31.10.2015        its a  long Event
    01.11.2015     30.11.2015        its a  long Event
    01.12.2015     31.12.2015        its a  long Event
    01.01.2016     01.01.2016        its a  long Event
```

This question is extension of [How to bind Repeater with list of objects GroupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907874/how-to-bind-repeater-with-list-of-objects-groupby).

I actually need some idea that how I can split it.

Comment: and what is the problem you are facing exactly ?

Comment: I actually need some idea that how I can split it.

Comment: I think he wants one entry for each month thats in this range.

Comment: Isnt your output wrong? Shouldn't the third line by `01.12.2005 - 31.12.2005` ?

Comment: I have edited the question now

Comment: Then the fourth line is still wrong - shouldn't start with 01-01-2015 but 01-01-2016

Comment: @rbm corrected it. My brain is not working any more ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could try this:

```
DateTime MonthStart( DateTime d) { return d.AddDays(-d.Date.Day+1); }
DateTime MonthEnd( DateTime d) { return MonthStart(d).AddMonths(+1).AddDays(-1); }

IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime,DateTime>> SplitDates(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    var dates = new List<Tuple<DateTime,DateTime>>();
    var t = start;
    while (t<=end)
    {
        if (MonthEnd(t)<=end)
        {
            dates.Add(Tuple.Create(t,MonthEnd(t)));
        }
        else
        {
            dates.Add(Tuple.Create(t,end));
        }
        t = MonthEnd(t).AddDays(1);
    }
    return dates;
}

void Main()
{
    var start = new DateTime(2015,10,05);
    var end = new DateTime(2016,01,01);
    var dates = SplitDates(start,end);
    dates.ToList().ForEach(d => Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}",d.Item1.ToShortDateString(),d.Item2.ToShortDateString()));
}
```

running above produces

```
05/10/2015 -> 31/10/2015
01/11/2015 -> 30/11/2015
01/12/2015 -> 31/12/2015
01/01/2016 -> 01/01/2016
```

**EDIT**
Few more runs:

Running between `2015-10-05` and `2015-11-01` produces

```
05/10/2015 -> 31/10/2015
01/11/2015 -> 01/11/2015
```

and running between `2015-12-01` and `2015-12-10` produces

```
10/12/2015 -> 12/12/2015
```

So that should be what you need.